# Distributing In-House iPad app is now generating code signing error in Lion using Xcode 4.3.2 (4E2002)

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

After upgrading our Jenkins CI Mac mini to Lion and Xcode 4.3.2 (4E2002) we now receive an

> unrecognized status -67068 from code signing

In the past code signing worked just fine, before we upgraded to Lion and the new Xcode.  Now that all our developers are using Lion and the new version of Xcode, we were forced to update our CI box.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

May 10 18:17:49 unknown installd[70] : unrecognized status -67068 from codesigning library

May 10 18:17:49 unknown installd[70] : 00281000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620415

May 10 18:17:49 unknown installd[70] : 00281000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.aKaDJC/foo_extracted/Payload/Test.app

May 10 18:17:49 unknown installd[70] : 00281000 install_application: Could not preflight application install

May 10 18:17:49 unknown com.apple.itunesstored[110] : MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1

May 10 18:17:50 unknown installd[70] : 00281000 handle_install: API failed

May 10 18:17:50 unknown installd[70] : 00281000 send_message: failed to send mach message of 71 bytes: 10000003

May 10 18:17:50 unknown installd[70] : 00281000 send_error: Could not send error response to client

May 10 18:18:18 unknown profiled[65] : (Note ) profiled: Idled.

May 10 18:18:18 unknown profiled[65] : (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.

Comment: FYI. Here is the description of the error from Apple: Cannot find code object on disk. You can get this error if you specify a location on disk and the system can’t find the code at that location, or if the system is checking the validity of running code and it can’t find the code on disk that was the source for the code in memory. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/CodeSigningRef/Reference/reference.html